# Inside Roots of Determinant of Polynomial Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let ${\bf A}(x)$ be an $(n-1) \times n$ polynomial matrix and ${\bf b}(x)$ be a $1 \times n$ polynomial vector. Suppose that

$$ \det\begin{bmatrix} {\bf A}(x) \\ {\bf b}(x) \end{bmatrix}=0 $$

does not have a root inside the unit circle.

What condition must a $1 \times n$ constant vector ${\bf c}$ satisfy in order for

$$ \det\begin{bmatrix} {\bf A}(x) \\ {\bf b}(x) - {\bf c} \end{bmatrix}=0 $$
to have a root inside the unit circle?

---

I guess it is useful to use the fact that

$$ \det\begin{bmatrix} {\bf A}(x) \\ {\bf b}(x) - {\bf c} \end{bmatrix} = \det\begin{bmatrix} {\bf A}(x) \\ {\bf b}(x)  \end{bmatrix}-\det\begin{bmatrix} {\bf A}(x) \\  {\bf c} \end{bmatrix},$$

which means, in particular, that ${\bf c}={\bf b}(x_0)$ for some $x_0$ inside the unit circle is a sufficient condition.

Comment: I'm having a problem with some ambiguities.  Could you write out an explicit example?  In any case, the problem should be related to the null-space or alternatively the linear dependence implied by the first statement.

Comment: @rrogers I think I have found the solution for this. It is simple, but I haven't written it as an answer because I am not sure it is a necessary condition, though I am pretty sure it is sufficient. The condition is that there exists a vector ${\bf v}$ and some $x_0$ inside the unit circle such that ${\bf c} = {\bf b}(x_0) + {\bf v}{\bf A}(x_0) $. What do you think?

Comment: I still don't understand the problem: is the matrix a matrix of polynomials or a coefficient matrix that can be applied to the vector [1,x,x^2..] ?

Comment: @rrogers It is a matrix of polynomials, each element of the matrix is a polynomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A necessary and sufficient condition is that there exists a vector $\bf v$ and some $x_0$ inside the unit circle such that ${\bf c} = {\bf b}(x_0)+{\bf vA}(x_0)$.

If this is the case then

$$ \det\begin{bmatrix} {\bf A}(x_0) \\ {\bf b}(x_0) - {\bf c} \end{bmatrix} = \det\begin{bmatrix} {\bf A}(x_0) \\ {\bf vA}(x_0)  \end{bmatrix}=0.$$

Since

$$ \det\begin{bmatrix} {\bf A}(x) \\ {\bf b}(x) \end{bmatrix}=0 $$

does not have a root inside the unit circle, it follows that ${\bf A}(x)$ has full row rank for all $x$ inside the unit circle. Therefore, if the condition is not satisfied ${\bf b}(x) - {\bf c}$ will not be linearly dependent with the rows of ${\bf A}(x)$ for all $x$ in the unit circle, so that

$$ \det\begin{bmatrix} {\bf A}(x) \\ {\bf b}(x)-{\bf c} \end{bmatrix}= 0 $$

does not have an inside root.